# tomcat java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: tomcat, server

Version: Tomcat 8.5

The server keeps getting the following error:

```
org.apache.coyote.http11Processor.service Error processing request
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:389)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
```

The way i tried
Check default name=localhost in server.xml

Do you know what else to check?? I don't know what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with access logging in Tomcat circa version 8.5.4 - 8.5.13.  It appears to be resolved in versions >=8.5.14 with a null check:

```
                // If the context is null, it is likely that the endpoint was
                // shutdown, this connection closed and the request recycled in
                // a different thread. That thread will have updated the access
                // log so it is OK not to update the access log here in that
                // case.
                if (context != null) {
                    context.logAccess(request, response,
                            System.currentTimeMillis() - req.getStartTime(), false);
                }
```

I would suggest upgrading to at least 8.5.14 (if not the latest 8.5.X).